# Does a program started with mpiexec know it was started with mpiexec?

Tags: fortran, mpi

I'm in the process of adding an option to a Fortran program to run it using multiple processors using MPI.  If the user is going to run it in parallel, the user needs to specify different input files---one file for each domain (processor) of the problem.  The program will look for a specific filename by default (a file called "serial.inp").  So I need the program to know when it is being run in parallel so that it can instead look for the other filenames instead (e.g. "parallel_1.inp", "parallel_2.inp", "parallel_3.inp", etc.).  My first thought is to have the user pass an argument to the program when they execute it, e.g.:

mpiexec -n 4 myprogram.exe -parallel

This way, it will look for the parallel files when that argument is present.  But it seems kind of redundant.  If the program is being called with mpiexec, there is no question that the user is attempting to run it in parallel.  Is there any way that my program will know it was started using mpiexec?  Or is the command line argument my best bet?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Alex Leach is right in that you can do this with MPI-implementation-specific environment variable lookups, but there's no portable way to do this.

But as I understand, I don't think you really need to; you can get most of what you want with just checking to see if it was run with one rank:

```
program filenames
    use mpi
    implicit none

    integer :: comsize, rank, ierr
    character(len=128) :: inputfilename

    call MPI_Init(ierr)

    call MPI_Comm_size(MPI_COMM_WORLD,comsize,ierr)
    call MPI_Comm_rank(MPI_COMM_WORLD,rank,ierr)

    if (comsize == 1) then
        inputfilename = 'serial.inp'
    else
        write(inputfilename, '(A,I0,A)'), 'parallel_',rank,'.imp'
    endif

    write(*,'(I,1X,A)'), rank, trim(inputfilename)

    call MPI_Finalize(ierr)
end program filenames
```

Running gives

```
$ mpirun -np 4 ./filenames
           0 parallel_0.imp
           1 parallel_1.imp
           2 parallel_2.imp
           3 parallel_3.imp
$ ./filenames
           0 serial.inp
```

That's not perfect; it'll give the serial result if you run using `mpirun -np 1 filenames`, but depending on your use case that may not be a terrible thing in exchange for having something portable.

Comment: This is exactly what I was looking for.  My parallelization of this code is pretty rigid.  The user is required to use the same number of procs as there are domains in their model.  If they only have 1 domain, it will be a serial run, so the "-np 1" problem is not actually a problem for me.  In other words, there cannot be a case where they only have one parallel file "parallel_1.inp".  They must have "serial.inp" or more than one "parallel_*.inp" files.  They will get an error message otherwise.

Answer (score 2):

Processes run with `mpiexec` will have various environment variables set, indicating to the subprocesses whether they are the master process or slaves, amongst other things.

Look in your `mpiexec`'s documentation for specific details. Microsoft have [some documentation online](http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/gg243459%28v=ws.10%29.aspx#BKMK_MPIEXECEnvironmentVariables) too.

Answer (score 2):

Why not do it programmatically? This is how I do it in my program:

```
#ifdef MPI
  CALL MPI_Init(ierr)                    ! Initialize MPI
  CALL MPI_Comm_rank(mpicomm,nproc,ierr) ! Who am I?
  CALL MPI_Comm_size(mpicomm,size,ierr)  ! How many processes?
#else
  nproc = 0
  size  = 1
#endif
```

After this point in the program, you can inquire whether the program is serial or parallel by inquiring the value of `size`.

Comment: This is somewhat different problem. As I understand it rks knows he compiled his program with -DMPI but he wants runtime detection of the means of execution.

Comment: Correct me if I'm wrong, but wouldn't the first portion of the ifdef statement (MPI calls) execute only if the source is built with MPI support (mpif90) and then second portion (else) will be executed if the code is not compiled with such support?  If so, this solution would still look for the parallel files, even if the code is executed without mpirun (as long as it was built with MPI support). I want it to look for serial.inp when it is executed by typing ./myprogram.exe, whether it was built with MPI support or not.

Comment: You are correct. Look at Jonathan Dursi's answer which is an extension of my example. The part of the code that checks whether it's a single or multiple process program and decides what input files to use needs to be implemented by you. So, my point is, for your problem, you don't need to worry about whether the program is run by `mpiexec` or not, or whether the code is compiled with `-DMPI` or not. You care about how many processes are there, and this information is provided by the variable `size` in the example above.